# Recommending Products in Shopify based on questions using Tags

Tags: javascript, shopify

I was designing a Questionnaire in which in based of your answers it looks for products you would be interested in. Only thing is I can't find how to search for the tags in my program. I found collection.all_tags and product.tags, am I on the right track? If so how would I proceed to once it finds the answer in the tags, what would be the phrase to call the product based on the tag that is in relation to the answer? Of course the answer you give in the questionnaire will be the tag, but what is the program to call that particular product which has that tag?

I'm doing the code in sections.
But for example this code doesn't work I don't know what's wrong:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}

{% if product.tags contains "particular_tag" %}

var bank=product;

{% end if %}

{% end for %}
```

and then displaying bank, I would like to do it based on the answer instead of the "particular_tag" but I'm doing it by parts, and the first part doesn't work.

Comment: For using this in a new section, I'd need to add something to the template of product? So that product.tags actually works right? I'm just not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% assign particular_product ='' %}
 {% for product in collections.all.products %}
  {% if product.tags contains "particular_tag" %}
   {% assign particular_product = particular_product | append: product.handle | append: '#' %}
  {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

You can then split the "particular_product" like this.

```
 {% particular_product_split = particular_product | split: '#' %}
```

then to go to each product, can do something like this.

```
  {% for product in particular_product_split %}
    <h1> {{ all_products[product].title }}</h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank You very much I'll give it a try, but I can use this type of format while coding in sections? It's just that the examples inside sections uses formatts differently like for () { etc.

Comment: yes, as long as the file extension is .liquid.

If this solved your problem, please marked it.